# How to get selected radio button in div of form in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, radio-button

I have a form has many divs and actions to a `servlet` to check whether user makes right or wrong every questions. Each div is a multiple choice question created by `java` code.

`jsp` file

```
<form id="doExam" name="doExam" action="CheckAnswer" method="POST">
     <% for (int i = 0; i < NumofQuestions; i++) {
        Question q = (Question) exam.get(i); %>

        <div id="question">
           <p> <b>Question <%=i+1%>:</b> <%=q.getContent()%></p>
           <p> <b>A.</b> <input type="radio" name="<%=q.getId()%>" value="A"> <%=q.getAnswerA()%> </p>
           <p> <b>B.</b> <input type="radio" name="<%=q.getId()%>" value="B"> <%=q.getAnswerB()%> </p>
           <p> <b>C.</b> <input type="radio" name="<%=q.getId()%>" value="C"> <%=q.getAnswerC()%> </p>
           <p> <b>D.</b> <input type="radio" name="<%=q.getId()%>" value="D"> <%=q.getAnswerD()%> </p>
        </div>

        <%
           String selected = request.getParameter(q.getId()); // ****** //
           list_answer.add(selected);
         }

         session.setAttribute("user_answer", list_answer); %>

     <input type="submit" value="Finish Exam">
</form>
```

The variable `selected` (at the line has comment) always got `null`. So that all of the `list_answer` items are `null` too. Are there any ways to get the selected radio button of the `question` div?

Comment: The **first time** the jsp is rendered, what would have put `q.getId()` as a request parameter?

Comment: q.getId() is the name of the radio button, and I think request.getParameter(q.getId()) will be returned the selected radio button, but it doesn't work, I ask everyone to find some solutions.

Comment: is q.getId unique? only then q.getId in your request.getParameter would work else you need to put the For loop and try to get request.getParamter of each q.getId()

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is that selecting a radio button and setting the value of it to `String selected` in the same `jsp/Servlet` file.

This is impossible using `request.getParameter(q.getId())`, since a HttpServletRequest is created once you submit the form.
After form submission, the request parameters will be set to request object and it is accessible to your action servlet/jsp `CheckAnswer`. That's why you are always getting `null`in the current page.

One of the solution to set radio button value to session object can be done using javaScript.
Check this article [Pass variables from client side to server side](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)